# Why my code works only sometimes ReactJS NodeJS PostegreSQL?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have PERN web-app, it has a function to create some entity in PostegreSQL (form includes 2 inputs type="file", one for video, 1 for multiply photos. 1 video and 1 photo will renamed and saved in folder 'static', all other photos will renamed and saved in folder too, but will saved in enother entity just with photos). It works, but it works ~1 of 10 times. What is the happening reason ?

formData:

```
  const addCar = () => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('price', Number(price).toLocaleString('ru'))
        formData.append('carNameId', Number(car.selectedCarName.id))
        formData.append('year', `${year}`)
        formData.append('motor', motor)
        let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
        formData.append('date', date)
        formData.append('video', video)
        formData.append('image', images[0])
        Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
            formData.append('images', image);
        });
        createCar(formData).then(() => setCarVisible(false))
}
```

API:

```
export const createCar = async (car) => {
    const {data} = await $authHost.post('api/car', car)
    return data
}
```

controller NodeJS:

```
class CarController {
    async create(req,res,next){                                
        try{
            let {price, carNameId, year, motor, date} = req.body        
            const {video, image, images} = req.files;                                                                 
            let videoName = uuid.v4() + '.mp4';                                                           
            video.mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'..', 'static', videoName));                                      
            let imgName  = uuid.v4() + '.jpg';
            image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'..', 'static', imgName))
            const car = await Car.create( {price,carNameId,year,motor,date,video: videoName,image: imgName})       
                for (let i = 0; i<images.length;i++) {
                    imgName = uuid.v4() + '.jpg'
                    images[i].mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'..', 'static', imgName))
                    CarImages.create({
                        img: imgName,
                        carId: car.id
                    })
            }
            return res.json(car)                        
        } catch (e){
            next(ApiError.badRequest(e.message))     
        }
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
const Car = sequelize.define('car', {
    id:                  {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},      
    price:               {type: DataTypes.STRING,    allowNull: false },        
    carNameId:           {type: DataTypes.INTEGER,   allowNull: false },         
    year:                {type: DataTypes.INTEGER,   allowNull: false},        
    motor:               {type: DataTypes.STRING,    allowNull: false },         
    date:                {type: DataTypes.STRING,    allowNull: false },          
    video:               {type: DataTypes.STRING,    allowNull: false },           
    image:               {type: DataTypes.STRING,    allowNull: false }            
})

const CarImages = sequelize.define('car_images', {
    id:                  {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    img:                 {type: DataTypes.STRING,    allowNull: false}
})

Car.hasMany(CarImages, {as: 'images'})
CarImages.belongsTo(Car)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because of the event of the button tag in your JSX. It force re-render your component w / o waiting your xhr finished. That is the reason of sometimes working process. If xhr was faster than component was re-rendered the action will success. Use your action like this:

Just get the event in your click handler and delete default events.

**OR** use *div* instead of button tag

```
const addCar = (**event**) => {
        **event.preventDefault();**
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('price', Number(price).toLocaleString('ru'))
        formData.append('carNameId', Number(car.selectedCarName.id))
        formData.append('year', `${year}`)
        formData.append('motor', motor)
        let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
        formData.append('date', date)
        formData.append('video', video)
        formData.append('image', images[0])
        Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
            formData.append('images', image);
        });
        createCar(formData).then(() => setCarVisible(false))
}
```